# Callback works when called without parameter but not with

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have a jQuery function:

```
$(".foo").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
});
```

I'd like to extract the function:

```
function logEventType(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
}
```

When I try to call it with the parameter:

```
$(".foo").click(logEventType(event));
```

it runs automatically on page load and doesn't operate on click function. However, if I call it without the parameter:

```
$(".foo").click(logEventType);
```

it runs exactly like I'd hope. I guess I have it working fine, but I'm just wondering what's going on and why.

Comment: There's a difference in calling a function, and referencing a function that *will be called later*. When you add parentheses you call the function, always, and return the result, which would be `undefined` unless you've specified another return value from the function, so you're basically doing `$(".foo").click(undefined);`, which won't work, all you want is a reference to the function, which you get by just using it's name.

Comment: this *must* be a repeat of many other questions - simple answer - you have to pass the function reference, not the _result of calling the function_

Comment: Because in the second example you're passing the reference to the function rather than calling it immediately which is how it works. See also `setTimeout(fn(), 1000)` and `setTimeout(fn, 1000)`. The latter is the correct version.

Comment: "I'm just wondering what's going on and why." It's the nature of callbacks. You pass the reference to the function, without the parameters. Much like with delegates and event delegations, it infers the signature — it knows which arguments will be passed and resolve them when you click.

Comment: If you inline the function again, `$(".foo").click(logEventType(event));` becomes `$(".foo").click(function(event) { console.log(event.type); }(event));`. Since you are not doing this in your first example either, why would you add `(event)` later?

Answer (score -1):

.click expects anonymous func or callback func. when you pass func(), it executes immediately. But we pass callback func, the jquery will call this func when the associated event occurs with event parameter,so you can get access that parameter